# How can I pool connections using psycopg and gevent?

Tags: python, postgresql, asynchronous, gevent, psycopg

The psycopg docs state: "Psycopg connections are not green thread safe and can’t be used concurrently by different green threads. Trying to execute more than one command at time using one cursor per thread will result in an error (or a deadlock on versions before 2.4.2).
Therefore, programmers are advised to either avoid sharing connections between coroutines or to use a library-friendly lock to synchronize shared connections, e.g. for pooling."

I can't find an implementation of pool that is green thread safe - are there any out there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you know [gevent-psycopg2](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/gevent-psycopg2) module, which makes `psycopg` greenlet-friendly.

Looking for connection pooling solution I've tried 2 solutions:

- `SQLALchemy` - it seems to work properly with monkey-patched threads and `gevent-psycopg2`. The [`QueuePool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool) class uses `threading` module internally for locking, monkey patching is thus necessary, even though `gevent-psycopg2` makes `psycopg2` green.
- there's a `psycopg2` [connection pooling example](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/psycopg2_pool.py) in `gevent` examples

I've tried both solutions, but not at production load - so I can't say about their robustness yet.

Comment: Ended up using the connection pooling example in the gevent docs

Comment: Updated link to psycopg2 gevent example: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/psycopg2_pool.py

Comment: Update: this lib has been declared "obselete" in favor of: https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/

Answer (score 4):

If you call `gevent.monkey.patch_thread()` you should be able to use `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool`.

- docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html#psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool
- source: https://github.com/dvarrazzo/psycopg/blob/2_4_5/lib/pool.py#L173

Comment: Is this correct? Isn't this for multi threading as opposed to for gevent "green" threads?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good pool (not just example, but used in production): [psycopg2_pool.py](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/psycopg2_pool.py)

Comment: is it possible to use it with sqlalchemy?