# Postgres database connection in python

Tags: python, postgresql, putty

How do i access a postgre database which is on a linux server machine in python?
I have accessed it with putty terminal but i need to access the tables in the database through python and I am unable to do that.

Comment: psycopg2 is the library used for connecting to postgresql http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

Comment: I tried psycopg2 but I was unable to because it kept returning an error, connection refused.

Comment: `connection refused` is not a _psycopg2_ library issue, it's typically a permissions/connection issue.

Comment: Post some code/ssh example, we may be able to help you.

Comment: I have entire module to make this async and easy.  You can see it here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted/49366850#49366850

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' user='dbuser' host='localhost' port='5432' password='dbpass'")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
    sys.exit('Failed to connect to database')


try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id < 10000")
    dbRecord = cursor.fetchone()

    if dbRecord == None:
        print('ERROR: First record not found', file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        print('Loaded {}'.format(dbRecord))
    dbRecordId = dbRecord[0]

    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Also you might need to allow access in postgres. To allow users connecting to server with login/password pair uncomment or add the following lines in `pg_hba.conf` (typically located in `/etc/postgresql/{postgres_version}/main/pg_hba.conf`):

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

**Edit:** oh, I just realized that your postgres server is on a remote machine. The following options may apply then:

- Add your IP to the `pg_hba.conf` configuration above and change `host='localhost'` to `host='your.server.address.or.ip'` in the script. OR:
- Use [ssh port forwarding](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html) to be able to access the remote server's 5432 port at your local machine. In that case leave `localhost` in the script as is.

The latter might be a cleanest and fastest option as you seem to already have the ssh access and you won't need to mess with database config that way. Moreover, you might not be permitted to change configs.

Answer (score -1):

To connect PostgreSQL with python, you need to install psycopg2 module. Additionally, there are some other modules like bpgsql,ocpgdb,PyGreSQL

Install psycopg2

## pip install psycopg2

You can also install a specific version using the following command.

## pip install psycopg2=2.7.5

Connect the PostgreSQL database and perform SQL queries on the database name you want to connect.
You ought to get the below output after connecting to PostgreSQL from Python

```
You are connected to -  ('PostgreSQL 10.3')
PostgreSQL connection is closed
```

Refer this link for complete guide:
https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/#targetText=Use%20the%20connect()%20method,connection%20after%20your%20work%20completes.