# Bottle and multiple requests

Tags: python, bottle

I developed an API with Bottle and some requests takes long time to send the response, the problem is if during this time I send another short request, I have to wait until the first request is finished.

Here is an example :

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from bottle import route, run


@route('/test', method='GET')
def test():
    return 'hello'


@route('/loop', method='GET')
def loop():
    for i in range(0, 1000000000):
        a = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':

    run(host='127.0.0.1', port=45677, debug=True, server='gevent')
```

If you run /loop and then /test you will have to wait until the /loop is finished to get the /test response.

I tried with many server, always the same problem.

What I'm doing wrong ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the async approach.  For instance with `gevent` async doesn't mean multithreaded, so anything that requires CPU will still block.  But this is great for stuff that relies on IO, like SQL queries.

So inside your `for` loop since that is merely cpu bound you will block until it's over unless you provide a `sleep` condition to allow other contexts to run during the process.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey,spawn as gspawn, sleep as gsleep, socket, signal_handler as sig
monkey.patch_all()
import signal
from bottle import Bottle, static_file, get, post, request, response, template, redirect, hook, route, abort
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler


def sample():
    gspawn(myfunc)


@get('/')
def app():
    return 'Hello World!'

@get('/test')
def test():
    return 'hello'

@route('/loop')
def loop():
    for i in range(0, 1000000000):
        gsleep(0)
        a = 0

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(port)), botapp , handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    sig(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    sig(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works with the test code, but not with my API, I have to do ```gevent.sleep(0.001)```.
There is an other solution with multithreaded ? I tried to create a process for the loop function with ```multiprocessing.Process()``` but it was the same problem.

Comment: It not solve the problem if in my loop function I have a long MySQL requests :/

Comment: Are you spawning new contexts for your requests?  Long SQL queries will not block if you are using a threaded connection to MYSQL

Comment: I use this for postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted/49366850#49366850

Comment: I'm using MySQLdb, I will check about contexts, thank you