# Flask + Gevent PyWSGI + MySQL Connector: Sometime got hung when get_connection from pool

Tags: python, mysql, flask, gevent

I'm developing a Flask server with Gevent PyWSGI and MySQL Connector as DB Driver. After monkey_patch to make it serving multiple requests concurrently, I found sometimes my server got hung with 2 or more concurrent requests and I have to restart server to make it work.
Detail:

- I set up MySQL Connection Pool (pool_size=10) and sharing this single pool instance over the application.

```
class PoolManager:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self._init()

    def _init(self):
        self._pool = MySQLConnectionPool(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def get_connection(self):
        #logging greenlet id
        print("Start get connection from pool....")
        print("GID {}".format(id(gevent.getcurrent()))) 
        new_cnx = self._pool.get_connection()
        print(" -------CONN_ID: {}".format(new_cnx.__getattr__("connection_id")))
        return new_cnx
```

- When running, at the beginning, everything seems to be okay, I saw the pool initialize 10 connection to MySQL and it works fine. Every coming requests have been served concurrently.
- After a random while, I did 2 more requests.. The stdout be stuck at exactly logging line above:

```
Start get connection from pool....
GID 123xxxxx
Start get connection from pool....
GID 321xxxxx
```

And then nothing happens. MySQL connections (via `show processlist`) are sleeping all and my server got hung.
So, my question is:

- Does I got race condition here? Where're the problems? Gevent Pywsgi or Mysql Connector?
- Which is correct approach here? A MysqlConnectionPool can not be reused over threads and should I init each connection for each greenlet?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a specific mysql module for gevent.  UltraMysql is located here:
https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql

You should look here at this example.  This is working great in all my production environments.

[Python Postgres psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted/49366850#49366850)