# Bottle and Mysql blocking request

Tags: python, mysql-python, bottle

I'm trying to figure out why my simple code have a blocking concurrent request:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
from bottle import route, run
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()


cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, db='db', user='user', passwd='pass', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")
cursor = cnx.cursor()


@route('/testlong', method='GET')
def test_long():
    cursor.execute('SELECT SLEEP(5);')
    return 'finished'


@route('/testfast', method='GET')
def test_fast():
    return 'finished'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='127.0.0.1', port=46677, debug=True, server='gevent')
```

If I run http://localhost:46677/testlong and at the same moment http://localhost:46677/testfast on a different browser, my second request have to wait that the first is finished (so 5 seconds).

What I'm doing wrong please ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The [docs](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#greenlets-to-the-rescue) seem to imply that you should be `yield`ing, not `return`ing.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you, I tried but it's not working too

Comment: Btw, you don't need the `coding` line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted/49366850#49366850

Comment: @eatmeimadanish this is what I finished to do, I modified this Package (https://github.com/hsxhr-10/PyMySQLPool) for MySQLdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MySQLdb` package is just a thin Python wrapper on top of a C extension, which means that `gevent` can't monkey patch it.

You should either use a pure Python MySQL client (like [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)) or use a different framework that supports threading (like FastAPI/Starlette).

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, please select it as the answer by clicking on the check mark.