# Optimal PostgreSQL connection method with Python in serverless environment?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have developed a Cloud Run service using Python with Flask that accepts incoming HTTP requests. Once a request is made, the payload is send to a class with a context manager. In that class, upon entering, a database connection is established. Upon exiting, it is closed, to ensure there's no connection leaks.

Here is how the database connection is set up in the class's **enter** method:

```
if self.db_connection is None:
    try:
        self.db_connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host=
            dbname=
            user=
            password=
            )
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error connecting to database: {e}')
        return
```

We are using Google Cloud SQL with a PostgreSQL V15.2 instance, connecting using the psycopg2 Python library. Because of this, there's a maximum number of active connections per database which is 100. Therefore we limit the amount of active HTTP requests/tasks to less than that, around 80, which is making the workflow slower.

There are definitely better ways, but I am not very familiar with them yet. One such way seems to be connection pooling, but I'm not yet sure about the best way to go about it. Because we have multiple active instances and connect to the database during a 'task', if we create a connection pool, won't multiple pools be created with each having a number of reserved connections? How would we go about making a single pool for, say, 80 connections that are re-used? Would a single pool with 80 connections then take up 80% of the max_connections per database for the Cloud SQL database?

What's the best approach in this situation? We'll probably reconfigure the database to increase the MAX_CONNECTIONS parameter, but it's probably also a good idea to change the way we connect to it at the same time.

### Specifications/information:

- Python 3.9
- Psycopg2
- Cloud Run using Flask
- Tasks created using Cloud Tasks with the Cloud Run and Flask app route as HTTP targets
- Number of HTTP requests (tasks), with each connecting and disconnecting from the database, will be a minimum of 10,000 per day but likely more, possibly up to 100,000/day
- PostgreSQL 15.2 on Google Cloud SQL
- All hosted on Google Cloud Platform inside of a VPC network

We haven't tried a different way of connecting, but the possible solutions/information I've discovered so far are:

- The various pooling methods in psycopg2: Abstract, Simple, Threaded, and Persistent
- Possible other connection methods in Cloud SQL as described in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run), however, we'd like to continue using the psycopg2 library and it doesn't seem like this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommended leveraging a connection pool for your use-case to take advantage of re-using connections and reduce overhead with upwards of 100,000 connections. A popular connection pooling library for Python that supports psycopg2 is [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

You could establish a global connection pool similar to your code above that could be shared across class objects.

The code for SQLAlchemy to establish a psycopg2 connection engine (pool) is as follows:

```py
import sqlalchemy

pool = None

def init_connection_pool(user, password, ip_address, dbname):
  return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
      # Equivalent URL:
      # postgresql+psycopg2://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
      sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
          drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
          username=user,
          password=password,
          host=ip_address,
          port=5432,
          database=dbname,
      ),
      # requiring SSL is recommended for Private IP connections
      connect_args={'sslmode': 'require'},
      # Pool size is the maximum number of permanent connections to keep.
      pool_size=10,
      # Temporarily exceeds the set pool_size if no connections are available.
      max_overflow=2,
      # The total number of concurrent connections for your application will be
      # a total of pool_size and max_overflow.
      # 'pool_timeout' is the maximum number of seconds to wait when retrieving a
      # new connection from the pool. After the specified amount of time, an
      # exception will be thrown.
      pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
      # 'pool_recycle' is the maximum number of seconds a connection can persist.
      # Connections that live longer than the specified amount of time will be
      # re-established
      pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
  )

# ... inside your endpoint code

global pool
if pool is None:
  pool = init_connection_pool("YOUR-USER", "YOUR-PASsWORD", "CLOUD-SQL-PRIVATE-IP", "YOUR-DB")

# acquire connection from pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
  # ...
```

I have just set some defaults for configuring the pool and they can easily be tweaked as you see fit.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for your response. I understand the code, but I'm unsure about handling the creation of an engine in a serverless environment like Cloud Run for each HTTP request. Currently, it appears that an engine is created for each task in the code you shared. Ideally, there should be a single shared pool of connections across the tasks using one such engine if I'm understanding correctly. I should mention that the Cloud Run service can have multiple instances and multiple tasks on a single instance.

Comment: I believe since the `pool` is a global var it will not be created each task. It will be created once per Cloud Run instance, on the first task. I believe all subsequent tasks will be able to share the same `pool` across them. I can look into this a bit more to double-check.

Comment: It's an improvement with the connection method for sure. If I have a pool_size of 10, on 10 instances, will it hit the 100 default MAX_CONNECTIONS? Or will that happen if those 10 connections of each of the 10 pools are also used?

The pool_recycle is also helpful for ensuring the pool is closed if the instance becomes inactive, but could that be configured to be sooner, e.g. when the serverless instance shuts down (perhaps because of an error, like memory overflow)?

Comment: If you have pool_size of 10 across 10 instances and all 10 pools are maxed at 10 connections then yes you would hit the 100 max connections. Although setting pool_size to 10 does not mean 10 connections are always active just that the max is 10. (this is an important detail to point out as most likely you won't be at the max so open connections will be less.) You can easily adjust MAX_CONNECTIONS to be a higher value if you are seeing your connection pools max out open connections.

Comment: Implemented it using your approach (global pool) and initialized pool before the first request using Flask before_first_request method. This in a serverless environment works & answers my original question, thanks! However, I seem to be getting an error with the connection pool being exhausted. The maxconn is set at 10 (per instance), with a maximum of 10 concurrent requests per instance, thus being over 100 maximum active connections (most idle). Yet, I get a ton (>50%) of errors that the pool is exhausted at 50 concurrent requests. How should I approach setting the pool params in this case?

Comment: @Nuxurious have you tried explicitly setting the `MAX_CONNECTIONS` database flag to 100? It seems from looking at `max_connections` on [Cloud SQL Postgres database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags) that depending on memory size of your instance the default value for max_connections can vary. It could be that your instance has max_connections default to 50.

Comment: the `max_connections` value is currently set at 600 across the instance. It seems to have been psycopg2's ThreadedConnectionPool implementation. Adding 2 extra maxconn's (12 total on 10 concurrent requests/instance), alongside the custom implementation of the ThreadedConnectionPool [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted), I was able to fix it. Big thanks to you for showing me the way - the program's obviously performing better now, alongside the DB instance.

Comment: to add, the with statement I used as a context manager for the connection object might have also caused trouble. After assigning it to a variable inside of a try-except-finally, closing the connection and putting it back in the pool, made a big (possibly the) difference as well.